# This program is running low on memory

Tags: technical-issues, warframe

So, my computer's been having problems running Warframe.  I run Warframe at the max possible low settings, and intermittently between games my computer would tell me I was running low on memory.

Some basic specs, I have an i5 that runs at 1.8Ghz, and 6gb of RAM, 2gb of dedicated VRam on a Nvidia 720M.  Now, I thought that the problem must have been not having enough memory, so I bought a new memory module, so that I now have 12gb of RAM, 2gb of dedicated VRam.

I'm still getting the same problem. My computer is running hot all the time, even with additional RAM, RAM that I thought would help alleviate the problem of running the game.

I'm not sure if it's just me, but how would I get "more memory" for the game itself? I've noticed in Task Manager that even when running Warframe, it only takes up 4-5gb of memory, still leaving me with plenty of leftover memory, yet my computer insists it is running low on memory. I have tried setting priority, and that does nothing as well.

Comment: How big is your swap file?

Comment: I can't find a reference but I get this when gaming all the time. I always have plenty of spare memory and I found something that says that windows 8.1 has a problem that it erroneously displays this error message. I'd assume it is lying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you're getting is about the **video** card memory. How much system RAM you have doesn't matter.

It's caused by two factors - Warframe uses a lot of video RAM and Windows is acting like a spoiled child.

For reference - I, too, have a video card with 2GBs of RAM (and a whopping 16GB of RAM as I also run virtual machines when I'm not gaming), and I get the same screen in Warframe and some other games. This is despite the fact that the system works well during games. In other words - Windows is throwing a fit.

There's a workaround, however. You can set Warframe (or Steam, if you're running the game through Steam) to disable Windows Visual Styles when running the game (right-click on the Warframe / Steam shortcut, go to the Compatibility tab and check the appropriate box). This should prevent the nagging Windows warning from appearing.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I've been struggling with this issue for such a long time, it's nice to get an answer that actually fixed that warning.

Comment: @memescientist I'm happy you like it. Personally I don't consider the workaround an actual fix - there's no real reason to turn of visual styles, it's just that Windows is being a crybaby... ;)

Comment: Right, but it helps since I run WF at fullscreen, and I hate having to be interrupted by Windows politely telling me I'm running out of memory.

Comment: @memescientist Of course - it's just that a real fix (IMHO) should be the ability to turn off the nagging screen once and for all.